# Jasper use json response to fill page header

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have the following json generated by a endpoint:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "id":"2",
        "type":"mytype",
        "attributes":
        {
            "header":
            {
                "name": "Name",
                "code": "Code"
            },
            "dataset": [
                {}]
        },
        "links":{"self":"http://localhost:1025/"}
    }
}
```

I use a JSONAdapter and query the "dataset" attribute do fill my report. It works fine.
But i want to add a page header that uses the "headers" part of the json response.

Is there a way of doing that without have the pass those informations via parameters?

Comment: Are you tied to a specific version of Jaspersoft Studio/JasperReports?

Comment: No. I'm using the lastest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to switch to JSONQL, this is easily doable.

Considering this sample json:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "name": "Bla bla bla",
        "date": "2016-01-01"
    },
    "dataset": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "val": 11
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "val": 22
        }
    ]
}
```

This would be the relevant JRXML fragment, if you want to access the 'headers.name' in a 'static' fashion:

```
<queryString language="jsonql">
    <![CDATA[dataset]]>
</queryString>
<field name="Name" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="$.headers.name"/>
</field>
<field name="Id" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="id"/>
</field>
<field name="Val" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="val"/>
</field>
```

If you want to access the 'headers.name' from the current iteration you need to have this for the Name field:

```
<field name="Name" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.headers.name"/>
</field>
```

In essence it translates to: navigate up the tree twice and then select 'headers.name'

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but the dataset is used to "iterate" a collection of data. If i set a field with the value "$.headers.name" and im printing a table with all fields, will this field have the same value for every line on the table?

Comment: True. I've just shown you how to get both 'dataset' fields and 'headers' in one step. I've considered the 'headers' part as 'static' data. If my assumption was wrong you need to fill in more details with sample JRXML.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's static and will only change between reports generation. Your solution didn't work because i provided a exemple of json not the actual one. But i guess it´s something with "$". Is there a way in JSONQL to get a property of a parent? Update the json provided

Comment: Sorry mate, i can do using the "$", just have to navigate through the json structure. I'm acception your answer. If you know how i can access the parent property ill would be very happy. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: That is also possible. Edited the answer with that variation.